need to use a backend pagination ag-grid react-data-grid
need to use backend pagination and do not load or send all data to ag grid how can i make this
<AgGridReact columnDefs={columns}
          rowData={filteredUser}
           rowModelType="serverSide"
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          paginationPageSize={10}
          pagination={true} />

${baseURL}/users?page=${currentPage}&limit=10 need to use it in agGridReact when i sent endpoint like this give me first 10 items and pagination is disabled and i have around 70 items total but previous and next button is disabled and give me 1 of 10 how can i fix this problem
